# Boolean naming convention: statement or questionn?

Tags: c#, boolean, naming-conventions

*(questionn is misspelled on purpose: stackoverflow does not allow the word "question" in the title)*

Consider a property **SomethingHasChanged**

This can be read as a statement, **SomethingHasChanged!**, or a question, **SomethingHasChanged?**

What are the conventions (C#) for naming booleans? As statements or as questions?

*Background*

All code of a client I work for, is written in Dutch. In Dutch there is a slight difference between these two forms that in English does not exist. Therefore we need to make a decision between the two forms. Example: **ErIsIetsGewijzigd!** vs **IsErIetsGewijzigd?**

Comment: [Duplicate of a CodeReview question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30914/boolean-naming-convention)

Comment: IMHO `SomethingHasChanged` should be read as statement. If I want to ask question, I would like to write: `HasSomethingChanged()`.

Comment: Both sound like pretty horrible names for the reasons you stated to me, Not sure where you are using this but generally you don't need a boolean to say something changed, you use events. Also, I tend to just read code as close to plain english as possible so it negates the question. so it becomes "if my item has changed"

Comment: It's always good to start with `Is...` or `Has...` since you see immediately that this is a `bool` variable which increases readability. It's also useful if you're searching for a property with intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Boolean variable or property is an outcome of an expression, therefore, it is not a question, but a statement.

If, instead, you are asking a question, which requires an operation to answer it, than it should be a method and may be named as such.

Answer (score 4):

Many boolean properties start with `Is` or `Has` , e.g.:

```
this.IsRed = this (object) is red
this.HasChildren = this (object) has children
```

Your name doesn't really fit this convention well:

```
this.SomethingHasChanged = this (object) has something that has changed.
```

To match this convention, I'd rename your property `IsDirty` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to communicate you read state or determine it on request. A property `bool HasChanged {get; set; }` can be called twice and it should result in the same stored value. However a method `bool HasChanged()` communicates it is going to determine it for you on demand.

Finally, as I am Dutch as well, `ErIsIetsGewijzigd` sounds like a command, therefore as I read it, it should set the property, i.e. `ErIsIetsGewijzigd(true);`.